# Chrome extension to redirect tab url

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am trying to create a chrome extension to redirect a tab url via a custom url. I browsed many already answered questions and tested many but did not find the answer.

```
my manifest:
{
  "name": "Price saver",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Price saving during online shopping",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": ["tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

my background.js

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {         
var currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
var newUrl = "www.dealtikka.com/out.php?url=" + currentUrl
return { redirectUrl: newUrl};
 },
 {
urls: [
  '*://*.*/*'
],
types: ['main_frame']
   },
  ['blocking']);
```

Nothing happens when I click the extension.

Comment: The first thing to do is to debug it, set a breakpoint in the background page or use console.log

Comment: Your posted code uses tabs[0] but it's not clear where it's from.

Comment: I changed my javascript to this... when I left click on the extension icon it works as if I made a right click.                                                 chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
  //Your code below...
  var tabUrl = encodeURIComponent(tab.url);
  var tabTitle = encodeURIComponent(tab.title);
  var myNewUrl = "https://www.dealtikka.com/out.php?url=" + tabUrl + "&title=" + tabTitle;

  //Update the url here.
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: myNewUrl});
});

Comment: chrome.tabs API is asynchronous, so by the time it is executed your original onBeforeRequest callback is finished. There was a similar/duplicate question on StackOverflow that showed how to keep track of the active tab's url - probably using chrome.tabs.onActivated.